# Javascript method similar to php file_getcontents

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any mehtod similar to file_getcontents in javascript or jquery.

```
<?php  $html = file_get_contents('http://m.uploadedit.com/b037/1405919727889.txt'); 
echo ($html);?>
```

This works fine but i dont want to use php i want to jquery or javascript i have tried this method

```
$(document).ready(function () {

         $.ajax({
              url:"http://m.uploadedit.com/b037/1405919727889.txt",
              type: "Get",
              success: function (data) {
                   alert(data)
              }
           });
});
```

But i get nothing. Any recommendations?

Comment: yo cannot access crossdomain files using html you will need server side scripting

Comment: @pareshm , why cant ? see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird but what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: You are not doing any thing wrong, run it on chrome it will will give  you error on console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do cross domain requests, you need to setup a php proxy, like, create a php file in your server say `get_contents.php`,

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://m.uploadedit.com/b037/1405919727889.txt'); 
echo ($html);
```

and in jquery, access your php, as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://your_server.com/get_contents.php",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks i know how to do it in php but i want to do same thing in jquery

Comment: @user3754380 but...man, you can't...it's like asking to draw 2 perpendicular lines that never touch each other...

Comment: @user3754380 you cannot access file thats on different domain with js

Answer (score 0):

Javascript cant get content of a file, but as you can see, php can. What I suggest to you is to work with togeter

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://m.uploadedit.com/content/somehash",
        type: "Get",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        }
    });
});
```

And in '/content/somehash' put a php file:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://m.uploadedit.com/content/somehash');
```

I suggest you to hide the real name of filename. If you expose information like that, what do you expect if some malicious user try to http://m.uploadedit.com/content/../../.htaccess (for example). The risk is to give too many information. And it's not a good idea.

---

Exists an alternative and its name is NodeJs:

```
fs.readFile('/content/somehash', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // here you can output the content ...
});
```

Comment: i dont want to use server side programming otherwise i would have done by myself i am looking for client side options

Comment: @user3754380 , jQuery is not given Those many permissions :) Sorry

Comment: So, ... if you dont want server side, ... why do you ask some content to a server? Why do you make http call?

Comment: Please READ MY QUESTION  i asked for the alternatives

Comment: You NEED server side. Client side cannot do what you need. So, ... Why you dont want server-side?

Comment: @sensorario , he has No server, he wants all to be in HTML file with jQuery

Comment: I think he can try NodeJs. Is Javascript, has access to filesystem. Make possible creation of a server in few lines of code.

Comment: @sensorario, NodeJS **is server side**. It's just that it's written in javascript...

Comment: I know: the question is about javascript or jquery solution, or alternative. So ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. I found this and working fine

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options) {
  if(options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
    var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
    options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
    //options.url = "http://cors.corsproxy.io/url=" + options.url;
  }
});

$.get(
    'http://m.uploadedit.com/b037/1405919727889.txt',
    function(response) {
        $("#content").html(response);
        alert(response);
});
```